# Using IAM for Azure Service Bus, how can I assign a role to an application?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

### Background

I want to give an application ownership of several of my Azure Service Bus queues ... specifically, by granting it the **Azure Service Bus Data Owner** role.

The Azure Service Bus documentation says this is possible:

> Azure Service Bus supports using Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) to authorize requests to Service Bus entities (queues, topics, subscriptions, or filters). With Azure AD, you can use role-based access control (RBAC) to grant permissions to a security principal, which may be a user, group, or **application service principal** [my emphasis].
>
> ([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/authenticate-application))

However, I can't find a way to do it.

### What I've Tried

1. Registered the application in Azure AD.
2. Granted the application the `user_impersonation` permission on `Microsoft.ServiceBus`. (`Application permissions` is disabled [1], so I selected `Delegated permissions` and checked `user_impersonation` [2]. No idea if that's right. I posted [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57379397/) a while ago about `Application permissions` being disabled, but the accepted answer of editing the manifest doesn't work in this case.)
   [image]
3. In my Service Bus queue, selected `Role assignments`.
4. Clicked `Add`.
5. Searched for my application.

### Issue

My application doesn't appear in the search results in `Role assignments`.

Comment: In Azure AD > App registrations > (app) > Overview > Managed application in local directory: do you see a link with the name of the app, or a "Create service principal" link? (In other words: does the tenant in question have a service principal for the app?)

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret That was it. There was no service principal for the app. Once I clicked the link, it showed up and I could assign it. If you post as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A service principal is the instance of an application in a given tenant. (Multi-tenant applications can have service principals in many tenants, all referring back to a single app registration.)

To grant an Azure role to an application, a service principal must first exist in the tenant. To check if the service principal for an app registration already exists in the same tenant where the app is registered (and create it if it doesn't):

Using the Azure portal:

1. Navigate to Azure AD > App registrations > (app) > Overview
2. Under the **Managed application in local directory** heading:

   - If you see a link with the name of the app, the service principal already exists.
   - If you see a "Create service principal" link, clicking it will attempt to create the service principal.

Using Azure CLI:

```
az ad sp show --id {app-id}
az ad sp create --id {app-id}
```

Using Azure AD PowerShell:

```bsh
Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "appId eq '{app-id}'"
New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId "{app-id}"
```

Comment: I have a similar problem that "Application permission type" is disabled. However the service principal exists. When I navigate to Azure AD > App registrations > (app) > Overview > Managed application in local directory: there is a hyperlink present indicating that the service principal is created. Could you please help me in figuring out what I might be missing? Thank you.