# Client credentials token retrieved through Client AAD not working on API Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to connect to API through Client AAD details(clientid,client secret) using "client_credentials" grant_type, I am able to fetch the token with API scope but when I use that token to retrieve API results, I am getting 401 unauthorized error.

I am trying to understand what kind of permissions are required on API AAD for Client AAD to accept the token. Please help me to understand this.

Following are the permissions on both AAD :

**API AAD:**

User.Read - > Delegated - > Sign In and read user profile

**Client AAD:**

User impersonation - > Delegated - > FOR API AAD

Microsoft Graph - Delegated,Application ->User.Read.All

Thanks,

Deepak.

Comment: Which API you are trying to reach?

Comment: Are you going to access the "profile" api? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/profile-example?view=graph-rest-beta

Comment: Please check if you have a valid access token for this API.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/cloud-partner-portal-orig/cloud-partner-portal-api-troubleshooting-authentication-errors

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-workThis can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Client Credential flow to obtain an access token, you must create an application and grant application permissions to the application (this is because Client Credential flow has no user interaction).

Before that, you need to understand the difference between delegated permissions and application permissions:

**Application permissions** allow an application in Azure Active Directory to act as it's own entity, rather than on behalf of a specific user.

**Delegated permissions** allow an application in Azure Active Directory to perform actions on behalf of a particular user.

Then you need to define the application permissions by editing the list of api applications.[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57379397/why-is-application-permissions-disabled-in-azure-ads-request-api-permissions/57385729#57385729) is an example.

Refer to this document and use Client Credential flow to get access token[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow):

1.First you need to get the administrator's consent:

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/adminconsent?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&state=12345
&redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/permissions
```

[image]

2.Then you can get the access token by sharing the secret:

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1           //Line breaks for clarity
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=535fb089-9ff3-47b6-9bfb-4f1264799865
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_secret=qWgdYAmab0YSkuL1qKv5bPX
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

[image]

Parse the token and you will see your custom `roles`:
[image]

Okay, now you can use the token to access your resources.

Comment: Thanks for the above details, sorry if my question was not clear, what all I am trying to do is, I have 2 AAD's, 1 API AAD, 1 Client AAD, there are two applications api and client which are associated to their respective AAD's. Now all I am trying to do is, by using the client's AAD ( client id and secret) I am generating a token for scope of API URL, If I use this token to call the API through postman, I am getting 401 unauthorized

Comment: @DeepakReddy Hi,can you use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your access token and provide screenshots?

Comment: @DeepakReddy   Can you provide your "Api"?

Comment: using Client Credentials grant type - https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPGuj.png , using user logged in token - https://i.stack.imgur.com/astsn.png , the second one works fine but the token of client credentials doesn't work

Comment: @DeepakReddy  There is no scope ("scp") in the first token. Lack of access to the API permission.

Comment: can you see this https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOeGV.png I am using the scope string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://deepak39api.azurewebsites.net/.default" }; to generate the token and full permissions are there for the client on the API