# Expose API with AAD token based Authentication using client ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, api, azure-active-directory

I want to expose `API` with `AAD token` based authentication using `Clients Id` and `secret`.

User how need access on `API` will request with `Clients ID`.
If we whitelist `client ID` for `API` access then `API` can be accessible using `Client ID` and `Client Secret`.

Like Kusto services accesss.

So need help how we can configure this `API` using Azure service's.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38494279/how-do-i-get-an-oauth-2-0-authentication-token-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, you expose an api protected by Azure, and then you need to request an access token using the client id and client secret to access the api.

First, you must create another application as a client application, then use this client application to access the api application, and you need to grant application permissions to the client application. It is recommended that you use the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).

Next, you need to define application permissions by editing the api application manifest. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57379397/why-is-application-permissions-disabled-in-azure-ads-request-api-permissions/57385729#57385729) is a example.

Then, grant application permissions to the client application.
[image]

The next two steps are done using the client application:

1.First, you need to obtain the administrator's consent:

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/adminconsent?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&state=12345
&redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/permissions
```

[image]

2.Request an access token using client id and client secret:

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1           //Line breaks for clarity
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=535fb089-9ff3-47b6-9bfb-4f1264799865
&scope=api://your-app-id/.default
&client_secret=qWgdYAmab0YSkuL1qKv5bPX
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

[image]

Try using the token to access your API.