# How to protect Azure Function Endpoints with custom roles and permission?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c

I need a starting point to solve the following problem:

Assume there is a model with different entities (e.g. school classes) and different roles that are connected to entities.

Now I want to check in my Azure Function if Bob has a role on this entity which entitles him to rate a student from the school class.

I think of a claim of the form:

```
TEACHER : [
 "class 2b" 
]
```

before.

Which Azure Resources do I need to map such a thing?

I already use Azure AZ for the ID token and my API is implemented in an Azure Function.

I would like to call Azure AD to get an access token which contains those roles and resources of my domain.

Comment: Hi have you looked into my answer? Any updates?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that this form is not supported by Azure AD.

The supported form should be `"{claim name}": "{claim value}"`.

If you accept this form, you can refer to my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63483491/how-to-add-a-custom-claim-and-retrieve-the-same-as-part-of-access-token-when-th?answertab=votes#tab-top).

What you need to modify is:

When you create the extensionProperty, you should name the extensionProperty as "TEACHER".

```
Post https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{object id of the Azure AD application}/extensionProperties

{"name":"TEACHER","dataType":"string","targetObjects":["User"]}
```

And update the extension property for your account:

```
Patch https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me

{"extension_6d8190fbf1fe4bc38a5a145520221989_TEACHER":"class 2b"}
```

Then you can get the custom claim as `"TEACHER": "class 2b"`.