# azure ad how to authenticate using token passed from another application

Tags: azure-active-directory, access-token

I am writing an asp .net MVC web application and I want to authenticate using Azure AD. The web application will not have a sign-in page. It has to be authenticated using a token passed from to it from another application. Really appreciate it if someone can help with an answer.

Comment: Have you made the api exposed?

Comment: There is a similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65934246/what-is-the-authentication-authorization-scenario-for-web-app-that-calls-api-wit/65955256#65955256

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirements, you need to create two applications in Azure, one representing the **client application** and the other representing the **api application**, and then make the client request an access token from the server,  and the server application will verify what the client application provides access token.

First, you need to **expose** the api of the  **API application** protected by Azure, which can be configured according to the following process:

**Azure portal>App registrations>Expose an API>Add a scope>Add a client application**

[image]

Then you need to create the **appRole** of the api application, and then grant that role as an **application permission** to the client application.

[image]

Next, go to **client application**>API permissions>Add a permission>**My APIs**>your api application.

[image]

Finally, you need to obtain an access token using the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) where no user is logged in:

[image]

Parse the token：

[image]

Finally, you can pass the token to the api application, and the api application will authenticate the client application by parsing the token.